# Perl JSON pound sign escaping

Tags: perl, json, otrs

I am trying to use a web API of a service written in Perl (OTRS).
The data is sent in JSON format.

One of the string values inside the JSON structure contains a pound sign, which in apparently is used as a comment character in JSON.
This results in a parsing error:

> unexpected end of string while parsing
>   JSON string

I couldn't find how to escape the character in order to get the string parsed successfully.
The obvious slash escaping results in:

> illegal backslash escape sequence in
>   string

Any ideas how to escape it?

**Update:**
The URL I am trying to use looks something like that (simplified but still causes the error):

```
http://otrs.server.url/otrs/json.pl?User=username&Password=password&Object=TicketObject&Method=ArticleSend&Data={"Subject":"[Ticket#100000] Test Ticket from OTRS"}
```

Comment: when you say 'pound sign', do you mean # or £? Please note that the name 'pound' is not universally recognised for the former.  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Uri::escape`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI%3a%3aEscape):

```
use URI::Escape;
my $safe = uri_escape($url);
```

See [rfc1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) for the list of characters which can be unsafe.

Comment: Of course it is like that... Was looking under the wrong tree.

Answer (score 5):

The hash symbol, `#`, has a [special meaning in URLs](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html#h-4.1.1), not in JSON. Your URL is probably getting truncated at the hash before the remove server even sees it:

```
http://otrs.server.url/otrs/json.pl?User=username&Password=password&Object=TicketObject&Method=ArticleSend&Data={"Subject":"[Ticket
```

And that means that the remote server gets mangled JSON in `Data`. The solution is to URL encode your parameters before pasting them together to form your URL; eugene y tells you how to do this.